# Replacing boost::functionN in C++11 with GCC 4.9.2

Tags: c++11, gcc, boost

I'm trying to build (in Windows) with GCC 4.9.2 the eGUI library by John Torjo, removing every dependence from `boost`.
In several files I find this typedef:
    `typedef std::function1 <void, event_type &> func;`
Compiling, I get the following error:
`.. \ .. \ Egui \ core \ detail \ event_handler.hpp | 44 | error: 'function1' in namespace 'std' does not name a template type |`
The boost documentation defines the **Class template FunctionN**:
`boost::FunctionN` - *A set of generalized function pointers That can be used for callbacks or wrapping function objects*.
Now, I ask: `boost::function1` may be replaced by some standard class?
In `<functional>` I don't seem to find anything that might serve the purpose.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should change all

```
boost::functionN<R, A, B, C, ...>
```

to

```
std::function<R(A, B, C, ...)>
```

(The N is irrelevant now, the standard library can calculate the N from the A, B, C, ... list)